# The listed items doesn't align and skip 2 item space in a row

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have problem in listing the products 3 in a row the line get broken at the 4th
when it's at the 4th item it's listing them like

```
1. row 1 1 1 
2. row 0 0 1
3. row 1 0 0 
4. row 1 1 1 
5. row 0 0 1
```

I can't find where is the problem.

I checked the bootstrap container structure. It's says the first col after the row is the left the second is the center and the third is the right.
I made 3 col in a row but that didn't work i can't use the left side it's like the container has only center and right side. So the size of the items not fitting the container thats why it's skipping as i find when i make the item size `<div class="col-md-2">` the items get in the line correct but they become smaller. I need them `<div class="col-md-3">` everything get broken when it's become 3 or 4

```html
<?php 


include "header.php";

$id=isset($_GET['kategori_id']) ? $_GET['kategori_id']:""; 

$kitap_cek_miktar = 12;

$sql=$db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS kayit_sayisi FROM kitap_bilgi where kategori_id=$id ");

$sql->execute();

$kayit_say=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$kayit_sayisi = $kayit_say['kayit_sayisi'];

$sayfa_sayisi=ceil($kayit_sayisi/$kitap_cek_miktar);
if (!isset($_GET['sayfa'])) {
  $sayfa=1;
}else{
  $sayfa=$_GET['sayfa'];
}
$ilk_kayit=($sayfa-1)*$kitap_cek_miktar;

  
   $resim=$db->prepare("SELECT kitap_ad,kitap_resim, kitap_fiyat,kitap_id from kitap_bilgi  where kategori_id=$id LIMIT ".$ilk_kayit.",".$kitap_cek_miktar);  
  $resim->execute();
 $veri = $resim->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // tablo verilerini oku
 
 ?>
<div class="container">
    <!---  this stucture is like a banner for an e-commerce website   --->   
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-title-wrap">
          <div class="page-title-inner">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="bread"><a href="index.php">Home</a> &rsaquo; Category</div>
              <div class="bigtitle">Category</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5">
              <button class="btn btn-default btn-red btn-lg">Purchase Theme</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9"><!--Main content-->
            
            <div class="title-bg">  <!---  this stucture is to change the list way an e-commerce website   --->
              <div class="title">Category - All products</div>
              <div class="title-nav">
                <a href="category.htm"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>grid</a>
                <a href="category-list.htm"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>List</a>
              </div>
            </div> <!--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--->

            <div class="row prdct"><!--Products listing the products pic, price, name --> 
            <?php foreach($veri as $kayit): ?> 
              <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- items list size  -->
                <div class="productwrap">
                  <div class="pr-img">
                      <a href="urun_detay.php?kitap_id=<?= $kayit['kitap_id']?>">
                      <img src="images/<?= $kayit['kitap_resim']?>" alt="<?= $kayit['kitap_ad']?>" class="img-responsive">
                      </a>
                      <div class="pricetag">
                        <div class="inner"><?= $kayit['kitap_fiyat'].'₺'?></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                    <span class="smalltitle">
                  <a href="urun_detay.php?kitap_id=<?= $kayit['kitap_id']?>"><?= $kayit['kitap_ad'].$kayit['kitap_id']?></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div><!--Products ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--->

              <ul class="pagination shop-pag"><!--pagination making the pages 1.2.3 next -->         
                  <?php for ($sayfa=1;$sayfa<=$sayfa_sayisi;$sayfa++) 
                  {
                    echo '<li>
                    <a href="urunler.php?sayfa=' . $sayfa .'&kategori_id='.$id. '">' . $sayfa . '</a>
                      </li> ';
                  }     ?>
              </ul><!--pagination--><!--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--->
      </div><!--Main content-->

            <div class="col-md-3"><!--sidebar listing the categories     -->
              <div class="title-bg">
                <div class="title">Categories</div>
              </div>
              <div class="categorybox">
                <?php categories();?>
              </div> 
            </div><!--sidebar-->
    </div>
</div>

<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Read up on how the bootstrap css grid works.  using `<div class="col-md-4 mb-4">` will give you 3 columns; the 4th column will wrap to the next line.  If you're wanting to display tabular data, use a [gasp] table.

Comment: I tried the thing you said when i do it the categories beside the items get out of the line and start to display under the items

Comment: could you add your new code to the post

Comment: i did edit it now

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood what the first diagram was supposed to illustrate.  I don't have time to sift through it right now, but it's probably a missing `</div>`.  What you can do to clean up you code is to start out with php stuff, and then do the presentation using php only for loops and variable presentation.  Using constructs such as `<?php foreach($veri as $kayit): ?>`  `<?= $kayit['kitap_ad'] ?>` `<?php endforeach; ?>` will make it much easier to see your html with proper indentation.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested but it didn't work and i sperated every div to make it easier to see if there is missing any div but it doesn't miss any.

Comment: That is so much easier to read! :) Try encapsulating the `<span>`, and temporarily removing the classes `pr-img`, `pricetag`, and `smalltitle`

Comment: I'm new just newly figured out how to put the code line in here :)   I've tried it. It didn't work it's only changed the way it's listing the price under the image.

Comment: My method is to simplify and get rid of confounding factors.  It may be time to just make a simple html proof of concept, and when you get that working, introduce it into your code.

Comment: it didn't work :D  Thanks anyway i'll change the template i guess